# script to show vsftpd users home dir size, last login time, last ip etc

Tags: bash, awk

Running into a bit of a problem here and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I'm trying to write a webpage/script that'll show our FTP users last login time, home dir size and last ip it was connected too from.

I've got them each working individually, but need help to tie them all together.

The biggest problem is this;

I've got a list of home dirs set as a variable

```
[root@myserver ~]# echo $userdirs
user1 user2 user3 user4
```

Now all I want to do is search the xfer log for these users and paste out the results (excluding everything else)

Here's where I'm stuck

```
for user in $echo $userdirs; do cat /var/log/xferlog |  awk '/10/ { print $4, $7, $14}'; done
```

This seems to run the command "/var/log/xferlog |  awk '/10/ { print $4, $7, $14}'" for each user in $userdirs

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Can you post an example line in xferlog where a user is represented?

Comment: Tue Jul 26 09:52:07 2011 8 10.70.11.11 70428730 /file.mov b _ o r backtofootball ftp 0 * c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

userdirs=(user1 user2 user3 user4)

awk '
BEGIN {
    for (i = 2; i in ARGV; ++i) {
        j = ARGV[i]
        users[j] = 1
        ARGV[i] = ""
    }
}
$N in users {
    print $4, $7, $14
}' /var/log/xferlog "${userdirs[@]}"
```

Replace `N` in `$N`  with the field number in `/var/log/xferlog` that contains the user.

Save it to a script like script.sh and run `bash script.sh`.

Possible minimized form of Awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=2;i in ARGV;++i){j=ARGV[i];users[j]=1;ARGV[i]="";}}$N in users{print $4,$7,$14}' /var/log/xferlog "${userdirs[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks, will have a peek at this, I should also h ave noted that the userdirs change daily so that'll have to be a variable too

Comment: If you like you could have `userdirs=("$@")` instead to accept arguments and run script with `bash script.sh user1 user2 ...`.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't appear to be too happy | awk: cmd. line:8: (FILENAME=/var/log/xferlog FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use array `users' in a scalar context

Comment: Well that's odd. I tested the script with /var/log/messages. Only that my values for the first fields are months. It seems to work fine. Can you post your modified script? And an example of `$N` is `$1`. That's the only thing you have to change.

Comment: I reproduced the error message here. Did you just remove `$N in`?

Comment: Doh, I missed the "in"  Thanks again!

Comment: One last question, it's showing every single log entry, I just wanted to show the last one. I've tried ` /var/log/xferlog "${userdirs[@]}" | tail -f 1 or sort` but no go

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Use the `-n` option not `-f`: `... | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 0):

FWIW you could tweak @konsolebox's answer a bit to just print the last entry for each dir:

```
userdirs="user1 user2 user3 user4"

awk -v userdirs="$userdirs" '
BEGIN { split(userdirs,users) }
{
    for (i=1; i in users; i++)
        if ($N == users[i])
            entry[i] = $4 OFS $7 OFS $14
}
END {
    for (i=1; i in users; i++)
        if (i in entry)
            print entry[i]
}
' /var/log/xferlog
```

I made a couple of other small changes, mainly stylistic and mostly because personally I just don't like the idea of parsing the ARGV list simply to pass in a string - IMHO that should only be used when you need to set variables to different values between opening different files.